# What's the meaning of "3D Universal Edge Routers"?

Tags: router, network-access

What's the meaning of "3D Universal Edge Routers"?

I often see this term on Internet, but I do not understand what it stands for.

Such as "MX240 3D Universal Edge Router", "MX480 3D Universal Edge Router" and so on.

Who can explain it?

Comment: Did the answer help you? If so, you should accept it so that it doesn't keep popping up. Alternatively, you could provide an answer yourself and accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**3D Universal Edge Routers** is Juniper Network's Series Product name. you can find more info in [there](http://www.networkscreen.com/MX-Series.asp).

`3D` means a physical, you can touch's product, it contrast to virtual product.
`Universal` means its usage vast, not limit to Juniper product, it can also join up to Cisco, Huawei and so on network products.
`Edge` means the Internet's edge. if you know networking knowledge you can understand easily.